# TinyMCE autoresize: Want to resize conainer divs also

Tags: jquery, plugins, tinymce, autoresize

I am using the Jquery TinyMCE (TinyMCE 3.4.3.1 jQuery package), and I want to auto resize the editor. For that I am using the autoresize plugin(plugins : "autoresize"...). My problem is I have a div for left panel and the tinymce is getting loaded in a div on the right. after resizing, I need to resize these 2 divs also, heightwise. I tried this

```
var resize_template_layout = function(){    
if ( parseInt(textarea_h) >0 ) { 
    var maindiv_h = parseInt($("div[rel=resizeMain]").css("height"));
    var tmce_h = parseInt($("#content_msg_tbl").attr("offsetHeight"));
    alert("textarea="+textarea_h+"\nmaindiv="+maindiv_h+"\ntmce="+tmce_h);
    h1 = parseInt(maindiv_h - tmce_h);
    h2 = parseInt((tmce_h - textarea_h))-h1;

    $("div[rel=resizeMain]").css("height",(maindiv_h+h2)+'px');
    $("div[rel=resize]").each(function(){
        var h_whiteDiv = parseInt($(this).css("height"));
        $(this).css("height",(h2+h_whiteDiv)+'px');
    });
}}
```

This only works if i call it after every thing is done and page load is complete, from an click event, or from console of firefox. But if I put this in the onInit, it doesnot work. The textarea_h is the textarea that is first displayed, and there is WYSWYG link to show the tinymce, so user can toggle between textraea and tinymce.

What I want to do is that when I show the tinymce I get the height of the editor and I adjust the height of the divs, and when i toggle back to the textarea, i revert back to previous heights. Is this possible?